# React Props.func is not a working for React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react. I find this problem when I run the react program. Its say "props.func is not a function"
My AddMembers.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom
import "../src/css/AddMember.css";
import '../src/data/data.json';
```

Part of the code of AddMember.js

```
const AddMember = (props) => {
 let movies = []; 
 const navigate = useNavigate();
 const [nameofmovie, setnameofmovie] = useSt
 const [moviepic,setmoviepic] = useState("")
 const [leadActor,setleadActor] = useState("
 const [rating,setRating] = useState("");
 function onChangeName(event) {
   setnameofmovie(event.target.value);
   }
function onChangeImage(event){
   setmoviepic(event.target.value);
  }  
function onChangeActor(event){
   setleadActor(event.target.value.split(",")
  }
```

```
  function onChangeRating(event){
    setRating(event.target.value);
  }
 const transferValue = (event) => {
    console.log('props obj:', props)
    event.preventDefault();
    const val = {
       "name" :nameofmovie,
       "picture of image": moviepic,
       "lead actor": leadActor,
       "rating": rating
    };
    props.func(val);
    clearState();
    navigate("/members");
  };
 const clearState = () => {
    setnameofmovie(' ');
    setmoviepic(' ');
    setleadActor(' ')
    setRating(' ');
  };
return (
    <div>
      <div id="topFormLayerOne" >
        <form>
          <div id="secondFormLayerTwo">
            <label id="labelFour">Movie Names
            <input
              onChange={onChangeName}
              id="inputFour"
              type="text"
              maxLength="100"
              placeholder="Movies Names"
              name="moviesName"
            ></input>
            <label id="labelFive">Picture of 
            <input
              onChange={onChangeImage}
              id="inputFive"
              type="file"
              maxLength="100"
              placeholder="Name of Images"
              name="imageName"
            ></input>
            <label id="labelSix">Lead Actor N
            <input
              onChange={onChangeActor}
              id="inputSix"
              type="text"
              maxLength="500"
              placeholder="Name of Actor"
              name="actorName"
            ></input>
            <label id="labelSeven">Rating</la
            <input
              onChange={onChangeRating}
              id="inputSeven"
              type="text"
              maxLength="10"
              placeholder="Rating"
              name="movieRating"
            ></input>
            <button onClick={transferValue} i
            <button id="removeButton">Remove 
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <p>{movies}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddMember;
```

My Members.js.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import jsonData from "../src/data/data.json";
import AddMember from "./AddMember";

function Members() {
  const [studentData, setStudentData] = useState(jsonData);

  const tableRows = studentData.map((info) => {  
    return (
  <tr key={info.id}>
  <td>{info.id}</td>
  <td>{info.name}</td>
  <td><img src={info["picture of image"]} alt=""></img></td>
  <td>
  {info["lead actor"]}
  </td>
   <td>{info. Rating}</td>
   </tr>
    );
  })

  const addRows = (data) => {
    const totalStudents = studentData.length;
    data.id = totalStudents + 1;
    const updatedStudentData = [...studentData];
    updatedStudentData.push(data);
    setStudentData(updatedStudentData);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <table className="table table-stripped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Actors</th>
            <th>Rating</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{tableRows}</tbody>
      </table>
      <AddMember func={()=>addRows()} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Members;
```

This is the json data file

```
[{ "id": 1,"name" : "Ticket to Paradise","picture of image":"../images/Ticket_to_Paradise.jpg", "lead actor": ["George Clooney, Julia Roberts"],"rating":5}]
```

If I don't add the navigate(), everything is working fine. But once I add the navigate, the error "Uncaught TypeError: props.func is not a function" occurs. The image also cannot work

How i am going to define image in json?

Comment: syntax error?? missing double colon  `const [leadActor,setleadActor] = useState("")`

Answer (score 0):

THe AddMember.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import "../src/css/AddMember.css";
import '../src/data/data.json';

const AddMember = (props) => {
  let movies = []; 
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  
  const [nameofmovie, setnameofmovie] = useState("");
  const [moviepic,setmoviepic] = useState("");
  const [leadActor,setleadActor] = useState("");
  const [rating,setRating] = useState("");

  function onChangeName(event) {
    setnameofmovie(event.target.value);
    }

  function onChangeImage(event){
    setmoviepic(event.target.value);
  }  

  function onChangeActor(event){
    setleadActor(event.target.value.split(","))
  }

  function onChangeRating(event){
    setRating(event.target.value);
  }
  
  const transferValue = (event) => {
    console.log('props obj:', props)
    event.preventDefault();
    const val = {
       "name" :nameofmovie,
       "picture of image": moviepic,
       "lead actor": leadActor,
       "rating":rating
    };
    props.func(val);
    clearState();
    navigate("/members");
  };
  
  const clearState = () => {
    setnameofmovie(' ');
    setmoviepic(' ');
    setleadActor(' ')
    setRating(' ');
  };
return (
    <div>
      <div id="topFormLayerOne" >
        <form>
          <div id="secondFormLayerTwo">
            <label id="labelFour">Movie Names</label>
            <input
              onChange={onChangeName}
              id="inputFour"
              type="text"
              maxLength="100"
              placeholder="Movies Names"
              name="moviesName"
            ></input>
            <label id="labelFive">Picture of Movies</label>
            <input
              onChange={onChangeImage}
              id="inputFive"
              type="file"
              maxLength="100"
              placeholder="Name of Images"
              name="imageName"
            ></input>
            <label id="labelSix">Lead Actor Names</label>
            <input
              onChange={onChangeActor}
              id="inputSix"
              type="text"
              maxLength="500"
              placeholder="Name of Actor"
              name="actorName"
            ></input>
            <label id="labelSeven">Rating</label>
            <input
              onChange={onChangeRating}
              id="inputSeven"
              type="text"
              maxLength="10"
              placeholder="Rating"
              name="movieRating"
            ></input>
            <button onClick={transferValue} id="submitButton">Submit</butto
            <button id="removeButton">Remove Movie</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <p>{movies}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddMember;
```

the Member.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import jsonData from "../src/data/data.json";
import AddMember from "./AddMember";

function Members() {
  const [studentData, setStudentData] = useState(jsonData);

  const tableRows = studentData.map((info) => {  
    return (
      <tr key={info.id}>
        <td>{info.id}</td>
        <td>{info.name}</td>
        <td><img src={info["picture of image"]} alt=""></img></td>
        <td>
          {info["lead actor"]}
        </td>
        <td>{info.rating}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  })

  const addRows = (data) => {
    const totalStudents = studentData.length;
    data.id = totalStudents + 1;
    const updatedStudentData = [...studentData];
    updatedStudentData.push(data);
    setStudentData(updatedStudentData);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <table className="table table-stripped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Actors</th>
            <th>Rating</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{tableRows}</tbody>
      </table>
      <AddMember func={()=>addRows()} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Members;
```

Here I rewrite the Member.js and AddMember.js.

Comment: This is not the answer, I just rewrite the two Member.js and AddMember.js